# Saving Ping command output into a variable with a batch file

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, cmd, ping

I am building a batch-file for some rudimentary ping connection monitoring on my network and i want to know how i might save the output from a ping command to string. later steps i would like to pull specific data out of that string as needed. Then i would like to do things based on the data stored in the string. such as play a sound when packet loss occurs.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the ping output line with delimiters *Space, Equal, Less*, and use 7th token if 8th token is "TTL".
This code works for me, it puts reponse time in miliseconds to environment variable %RESPONSE%:

```
SET IP=google.com
FOR /F "tokens=1-9 delims==< " %%a IN ('PING -n 1 -w 2500 %IP%') DO IF "%%h"=="TTL" SET RESPONSE=%%g
```